# The google abandoned the Eclipse as a development tool?

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently developed a project on eclipse and was published. Yesterday I tried to create another project and it was not possible. I went up to the developers website to download the latest version, and found not download the ADT. I found just downloaded the Android Studio. Does anyone have any info on this?
Obs .: Question made with Google Translator help. Excuse me anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, though Google may be extending support for Eclipse for a while longer, considering that:
Right after Android Studio 1.0 is released, Developer tools page has the following wording:

> Caution: **The ADT plugin for Eclipse is no longer in active
>   development.** If you're currently using it, you should migrate to
>   Android Studio as soon as possible. For more details about Android
>   Studio, see the Android Studio guide.

And now the wording has been changed to:

> Note: If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android
>   Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to
>   Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates. For help moving
>   projects, see Migrating to Android Studio.

Where they removed the statement *"The ADT plugin for Eclipse is no longer in active development"*.

Regardless, developing Android using Eclipse is something that *will* become impossible some time down the road, so it's better to download Android Studio now and start migrating your Eclipse projects with the help of [migration guide](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Android Studio is now out of beta and is the official IDE. The Eclipse plugin will no longer updated.